# How to create a record type more than one polymorphic variables

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml, record

```
type 'a item = { name:string; quantity:'a };;
```

This is a polymorphic type definition taught in Ocaml class. I'm trying extend this type have more than one polymorphic variables in item type like:

```
type 'a item = { name:string; quantity:'a; price:'b };;
```

But, I'm getting an error with unbound value b. So, what should be the type for the record type for more than one polymorphic variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
type ('a,'b) item = { name:string; quantity:'a; price:'b };;
```

As you can guess, you need to mention every type variable on the left-hand side. You did it for `'a`, it's only natural to do it for `'b` as well.

Comment: Haven't thought about a tuple for the type. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I suppose you have tried `'a 'b item` instead, I would rather have it that way. You're welcome. ;)